# Problem connecting with Dynamics Web Api after getting the token (node.js)

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm

I'm having some troubles to call methods of Dynamics Web Api.

With Adal I get the token, works smoot

```
function acquireToken(dynamicsWebApiCallback){
    //a callback for adal-node
    function adalCallback(error, token) {
        if (!error){
            //call DynamicsWebApi callback only when a token has been retrieved
            tokenTemp=token.accessToken;
            dynamicsWebApiCallback(token);
            callback(null,tokenTemp);
        }else{
            console.log('Token has not been retrieved. Error: ' + error.stack);
            callback(error,null);
        }
    }
    //call a necessary function in adal-node object to get a token
    adalContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, secret, adalCallback);
}
```

But, after getting the token, I try WhoAmI function, and fail

```
var dynamicsWebApi = new DynamicsWebApi({
    webApiUrl: resource+'/api/data/v9.1/',
    onTokenRefresh: acquireToken
});

//call any function
dynamicsWebApi.executeUnboundFunction("WhoAmI").then(function (response) {
    console.log('Hello Dynamics 365! My id is: ' + response.UserId);
    callback(null,tokenTemp);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    callback(error,null);
});
```

ERROR:

{ code: '0x80072560',
message: 'The user is not a member of the organization.',
status: 403,
statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
headers: '[Object]' }

---

I double checked directory tenant, client id, secret key. All it's ok.

Putting wrong params, I can't create token properly. So... It's ok

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: using the quid you get from `response.UserId` can you query `https://YOURORG.api.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/systemusers(YOURUSRID)?` your token might be from another environment

Comment: The reason may be you didn't create an application user for client credentials flow. Please check the step 3 in this [article](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/posts/dynamics-365-online-authenticate-with-client-credentials): **3. Create a new Dynamics 365 Application user**. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: As mentioned in comment, looks like you do not have application user been created in D365. Create an application user and assign it proper rights. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Correct, it's necessary to create an application user with application id and assign necessary roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, it's necessary to create a an application user with application_id and (important) assign all necessary roles.

More info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/create-users-assign-online-security-roles#create-an-application-user